# What is the best way to loop through function arguments?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, sapply

This feels like a really simple operation - compute the mean by group from one dataframe and merge it to another pre-formatted dataframe - my UDF does this and that is not really the part I'm struggling with.

What I want is for my function to iterate through a series(list, vector, etc.) of arguments.

I want to quickly be able to build a list (or vector - I'm not set on using lists) of variables and pass it to the function as the argument so it builds a dataframe with all the variables I feed it in that list.  My real database has 50+ variables and I want to make all different kinds of new dataframes with different combinations of the variables.  One list might have 5 variables, the other might have 25. But I'm open to the idea that I have something conceptually wrong and that I should be using a loop, purrr, map, apply, some other package etc. or change the way my function is written? What am I missing?

```
library(tidyverse)

data_sample <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Dalton Campbell", "Dalton Campbell", "Dalton Campbell", "Andre Walker", "Andre Walker", "Andre Walker"),
  Defense_Grade = c(88, 86, 92, 94, 97, 95),
  Tackle_Grade = c(66, 69, 72, 74, 76, 78),
  Coverage_Grade = c(44, 43, 44, 76, 73, 78)
)

#Here I set up the dataframe which the function will bind to 
data_sample_averages <-  data_sample %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(Defense_Grade_Average = mean(Defense_Grade))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)


#Function which computes average of variable (the only argument) and merges it back to data_sample_averages
get_avg2 <- function(v_name) {
  
  avg <- "_Average"      
  
  data_1 <-  data_sample %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(Name) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise("{{ v_name }}_{avg}" := mean({{ v_name }}, na.rm = TRUE))
  
  data_sample_averages <- merge(data_sample_averages, data_1, by = "Name")
  
  return(data_sample_averages)

}

#This works - it computers the average of Tackle_Grade and binds it to data_sample_averages
#However my real dataframe has 50+ columns and I don't want to copy and paste this line 50 times, changing the argument every time.
data_sample_averages <- get_avg2(Tackle_Grade)
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

#shows you the averages
print(data_sample_averages)
#>              Name Defense_Grade_Average Tackle_Grade__Average
#> 1    Andre Walker              95.33333                    76
#> 2 Dalton Campbell              88.66667                    69


#Neither of these work - this is where I'm stuck
#I want my function to iterate through a list of arguments which are essentially just character #strings in order for the UDF to work 
variable_list <- list("Defense_Grade", "Tackle_Grade", "Coverage Grade")

data_sample_averages <- lapply(variable_list, get_avg2)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Defense_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA

#> Warning in mean.default(~"Defense_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Tackle_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Tackle_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Coverage Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not
#> numeric or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Coverage Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not
#> numeric or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

data_sample_averages <- purrr::map(variable_list, get_avg2)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Defense_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Defense_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Tackle_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Tackle_Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not numeric
#> or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Coverage Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not
#> numeric or logical: returning NA
#> Warning in mean.default(~"Coverage Grade", na.rm = TRUE): argument is not
#> numeric or logical: returning NA
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you were not set on using lists, so I'm using vectors.

My solution relies on a function in the latest version of `dplyr`: the `across()` function.

```
library(tidyverse)

data_sample <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Dalton Campbell", "Dalton Campbell", "Dalton Campbell", "Andre Walker", "Andre Walker", "Andre Walker"),
  Defense_Grade = c(88, 86, 92, 94, 97, 95),
  Tackle_Grade = c(66, 69, 72, 74, 76, 78),
  Coverage_Grade = c(44, 43, 44, 76, 73, 78)
)

# The function
compute_avg <- function(.data, names){
    
    names_quo <- enquos(names)  
  
    .data %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(
      across(
        .cols = !!!names_quo,
        .fns = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
        .names = "{.col}_Average"
      )
    )
}

compute_avg(.data = data_sample, names = c(Defense_Grade, Tackle_Grade))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Name            Defense_Grade_Average Tackle_Grade_Average
  <chr>                           <dbl>                <dbl>
1 Andre Walker                     95.3                   76
2 Dalton Campbell                  88.7                   69
```

Comment: I've been struggling with NSE and this answer really helps!!! Looks like I also really need to learn across().  You don't have to answer me but I am confused by this line: ``` .fns = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE),``` what is the .x ?

Comment: Learning the functions in the new version of dplyr (>= 1.0.0) will give you a significant productivity boost: http://www.rebeccabarter.com/blog/2020-07-09-across/

It seems that you are not familiar with anonymous functions (also known as lambda functions) in the tidyverse. The `~` symbol is used inside many tidyverse functions to create functions on the fly. In this case, since the `.cols` are `Defense_Grade` and `Tackle_Grade`, the `.x` argument takes their values one after the other inside the `mean()` function. Finally, consider marking my answer as the solution if it solved your issue.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the education! I have lots to learn. Just started R this year! Thanks and I marked as solution!